# Python translating C saxpy

Tags: python, c, algorithm, numpy

This is the C code:

```
btemp = (*beta)/(*beta_prev);
for (k=0; k<xsize*ysize; k++) {
  parray[k] = zarray[k] + btemp*parray[k];
}
```

And I am doing the following in Python:

```
def saxpy(a, x, y):
    return np.array([a * xi + yi for xi, yi in zip(x, y)], np.float32)
#...
btemp = beta / beta_prev
ptemp = saxpy(btemp, parray, zarray)
parray[:] = ptemp
```

In my code, it seems to work fine (`zarray` and `parray` are changing constantly because they are inside a while loop).

But then I do:

```
btemp = beta / beta_prev
parray = saxpy(btemp, parray, zarray)
```

My code fail after iterating a couple of time in the loop, are not they the same?

Comment: Can you show how these all tie up in the for loop?

Comment: Which are you using, Python 2 or Python 3? What are types of `beta` and `beta_prev`?

Comment: Since the c is using a pointer, how do you initialize and modify them?

Comment: The code is a complex one, I'm not sure if it is good to post it. I'm using Python 2, and beta y beta_prev are float.

Comment: `zarray` and `parray` are 1d arrays with a size of `xsize*ysize`.

Comment: Did you try to put in the loop inside the python in the same way as the C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You changed `parray[:] =` to just `parray =`, which is not equivalent. The former assigns the content of `parray` on an elementwise basis, which is an important distinction if `parray` is not of the same type as the right hand side of the assignment.

Consider the two cases:

```
>>> xs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> xs[:] = tuple(2 * x for x in xs)
>>> xs
[2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> type(xs)
<class 'list'>

>>> xs = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> xs = tuple(2 * x for x in xs)
>>> xs
(2, 4, 6, 8)
>>> type(xs)
<class 'tuple'>
```